# Canon mg2550 printer: How to install printer driver?

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

I'm trying to set up a new printer but the problem is I never used Linux before.

It's a Canon MG2550 and the installation CD is only for windows. Firstly it doesn't appear on the list of printer types and MG2500 is the closest on the Canon website.

I think I have to set up a driver but don't know how.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Please include what version of ubuntu you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Go to the dash (the "start" button in the opper left corner if using Ubuntu or the button in the lower left corner if using Lubuntu)
- Click printers
- Choose Add
- Ubuntu will find the printer for you!
- Click the printer, choose "forward"
- If you want to customise the settings, click "Canon" and choose "forward"
- then scroll down to MG2500 (to the right it will say *MG2500 **series***)and take that!
- forward, enter your customizations, Click apply

### Done!

Comment: When I'm on-line, I'm on-line and I can help your mum... when I'm not, pray for someone else to see your comments!  And if I don't respond, try getting more reputation and shout for me in the AskUbuntu General chat room...

Comment: ok I will be back in 2 and half hours and will see if your online :)

Comment: @Fabby technically Linux has drivers https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47250/29195 and all drivers are modules and not all modules are drivers.

Comment: You know, I know and then look at OP's rep...  **;-)**  *Answer adapted!* And thanks for the upvote!  **:-)** @Enkouyami

Comment: Note for others, when adding it with the **green** `>printers>Add` button option did not work for me. I first installed the package below, and then the `>printers>Add...` button option still did not work. Instead I had to click: `>printers>Additional Printer Settings>` (which opened a different smaller window that was also titled "Printers") and then click on the **gray** `+ Add` button instead. Then I was able to click `forward` etc like @Fabby describes.

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution to this because I had the same problem, but I posted it on another question so now I can't post it again here. https://askubuntu.com/a/1268217/1117958

I also couldn't get the system to find the printer through the "additional printer settings interface" because it kept getting hung trying to search the database.

Here's what I did:

- Install cups-backend-bjnp
  `$ sudo apt-get install cups-backend-bjnp`
- Delete the printer.
- Add the printer.

Good Luck!

Comment: man, you are amazing! thanks