# Canon MG25505 Printing wrong colours

Tags: printing

My new *Canon MG25505* printer is working, but the colours are incorrect, because the set-up disk is windows only. 
 Thanks!

Comment: No, it won't work with wine. Wine is not for drivers or anything else with a low level interaction with hardware and peripherals.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Canon mg2550 printer: How to install printer driver?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/576859/canon-mg2550-printer-how-to-install-printer-driver)

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems like this. What I found was that I needed to go into the print settings and adjust the color mode. Print using system dialog > Color > Color Model

For my MG2522 the correct color mode is CMYK, but I only figured that out through trial and error.