# Fresh Install of 20.04: Canon Pixma MG2522 Cant Print from GUI or Terminal

Tags: printing, canon, pixma

lp -d (printername) (plaintextfilename) says it printed successfully in the logs but nothing printed.

"POST /printers/MG2500 HTTP/1.1" 200 391 Create-Job successful-ok
localhost - - [19/May/2020:21:30:16 -0400] "POST /printers/MG2500 HTTP/1.1" 200 274 Send-Document successful-ok
localhost - - [19/May/2020:21:32:03 -0400] "POST /printers/MG2500 HTTP/1.1" 200 391 Create-Job successful-ok
localhost - - [19/May/2020:21:32:03 -0400] "POST /printers/MG2500 HTTP/1.1" 200 274 Send-Document successful-ok

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Same issue here. My MG2520 prints fine in previous versions of Ubuntu but not in 20.04. I did notice that cups+Gudenprint v.5.2.1 accompanied the printer description in older versions of Ubuntu but not in this version. I read somewhere that Gudenprint was no longer supporting some of the Canon MPDs and I'm wondering if that isn't where the problem lies.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this by installing cups-backend-bjnp

`$ sudo apt-get install cups-backend-bjnp`

I then deleted the printer and re-added it.

Before I installed that package, it first called the MG2522 a "Generic Text Only Printer", but it would just freeze up when it tried to search for drivers.

Props to [@Niols](https://askubuntu.com/users/1117239/niols) for his answer here - [How to install a Canon PIXMA IP 3300?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1267655/how-to-install-a-canon-pixma-ip-3300)

Comment: Please do not send the same answer to different questions.

Comment: Apologies - what's the protocol for answering questions that have the same solution?

Comment: If the questions all discuss the same thing, then it would be better to flag the questions as duplicates of one of the questions rather than post the same answer numerous times.

Comment: This answer solved my problem -- Thank you