# How to install a Canon PIXMA IP 3300?

Tags: 20.04, printing, canon, pixma

After updating to Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, I find myself unable to communicate with my Canon PIXMA iP 3300 printer. I have tried several techniques:

1. Adding a PPA supposed to contain drivers for this printer. According to various sources (including https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/tutoriel/ppa_canon), either `ppa:thierry-f/fork-michael-gruz` or `ppa:michael-gruz/canon-trunk` or `ppa:michael-gruz/canon-trunk` should have it, but it seems to not be the case anymore.
2. Finding the drivers on the various Canon websites (Europe, USA, Asia, canondrivers, etc.) On most of them, I did not find anything for Linux. On Canon Asia, I found a driver for 32-bits RPM-based Linux systems. Conversions with `alien`, as suggested by some tutorials have proven useless on my 64-bits system.
3. Some other sources (including  for instance) contain long and complicated tutorials that usually involve patching together various RPM packages and installing them by hand.

Nothing, in my case, has proven successful. What is a (if possible clean) way to install my Canon PIXMA iP 3300 printer on Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: According to [the manufacturer's support page](https://www.canon.co.uk/support/consumer_products/products/printers/inkjet/pixma_ip_series/pixma_ip3300.html?type=drivers&language=en&os=linux%20(64-bit)) for this printer, they do not make a current driver for Linux.  It seems they abandoned maintaining drivers for it over 5 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

The page https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/tutoriel/installer_imprimante_preinstalles mentions (translation by me):

> *(Particularity of Canon printers: it is necessary to install the package `cups-backend-bjnp`)*

After that, the printer is recognized automatically by Ubuntu that marks it as "Cannon iP3300 series - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.3.3". Everything, including colours, then works out of the box.

Comment: this worked for me with Ubuntu 21.04 and a Canon iP2702 (usually shows up as iP2700 Series)