# Canon scanner not detected in Ubuntu 20.04 desktop

Tags: drivers, apt, printing, scanner, canon

I have configured a new install of Ubuntu 20.04 desktop.  I installed the printer and scanner drivers following the instructions at https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/05/canon-printer-scangear-mp-ubuntu-20-04/ and that installed the Scangear icon in my Applications menu.  I have a Canon PIXMA MG2522 (2500 series) printer-scanner all-in-one.  I also installed cups-backend-bjnp per the answer at [Fresh Install of 20.04: Canon Pixma MG2522 Cant Print from GUI or Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1241539/fresh-install-of-20-04-canon-pixma-mg2522-cant-print-from-gui-or-terminal).

The printer works, but the scanner does not.  When I open the Scangear icon it says “No Scanners Detected” and gives me the option to search for scanners – it searches for awhile and then says it can’t find any scanners.  My scanner is on and connected to the laptop.

The article referenced starts with:  `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thierry-f/fork-michael-gruz`.  When I installed it I got these messages:

```
Err:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon/ubuntu focal Release        
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Reading package lists... Done                                                  
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Finally, I went into Synaptic Package Manager and reloaded package information, and I got this message:  `“The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.”`

I just migrated from Windows to Ubuntu desktop.  The scanner works on Windows because Canon distributes Windows software, but I need this to work with Ubuntu.  I can print but I can’t scan.  When I go into Settings – Printers the Canon printer is listed.

Thanks for any help.

Per request from brian_p, here is the output from lsusb -v | grep -A 3 bInterfaceClass.*7

Couldn't open device, some information will be missing

Couldn't open device, some information will be missing

Couldn't open device, some information will be missing

Couldn't open device, some information will be missing

can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable

Couldn't open device, some information will be missing

```
  bInterfaceClass         7 Printer

  bInterfaceSubClass      1 Printer

  bInterfaceProtocol      2 Bidirectional

  iInterface              0
```

Couldn't open device, some information will be missing

Couldn't open device, some information will be missing

Couldn't open device, some information will be missing

Comment: I've never needed to download or add any drivers to scan with a canon printer on ubuntu. You may want to play with `scanimage` and produce some log info. I've never heard of Scangear, looks like something from Canon? You may get more feedback here if youre testing with the native Ubuntu scan software `simple-scan` (there may be more experience there). I am assuming youre connecting directly to the scanner and not through a print server?(that's where I've experienced this problem, with **saned**) but i'd start with scanimage and add some verbose output, `man scanimage` look at options there.

Comment: At first run `sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:michael-gruz/canon` and then retry running `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get install scangearmp2` and testing your scanner.

Comment: The SANE project claims complete support for the PIXMA MG2500 Series.  Your MG2522 is, I think, USB-only. Seeing the outputs from `lsusb -v | grep -A 3 bInterfaceClass.*7`, `sane-find-scanner` and `scanimage -L` would be very useful.

Comment: I ran the commands suggested by N0rbert and brian_p and they verified that the scanner is on, and it was detected by model number.  But the only way I got it to work was install Simple Scan, as suggested by @WU-TANG.  Contrary to what I read about simple-scan online, it does not put an icon in my Applications menu.  After installing it with sudo apt install simple-scan, you go to the command line and type simple-scan and it bring up the application window.  The application is very intuitive.  Thanks to all for your responses.

Comment: @RTC222 glad it works. I'm a bit surprised you had to install it though, it is usually there. In a desktop like MATE or GNOME Flashback it is under the "Graphics" Applications menu item. In the Unity desktop you would just search "scan". In both cases it shows up as "Document Scanner". Are you sure you are looking in the right place? If that didn't work you could use "Main Menu" menu editor from Applications-Systems Tools-Preferences or from the command line `alacarte` and just make a launcher for it as an Applications menu item.

Comment: I was rather interested in seeing the **actual** output for `lsusb -v | grep -A 3 bInterfaceClass.*7`. Any chance? TIA.

Comment: @RTC222 You asked for help; you got it. I asked for help; there is a deafening silence fro you. Such is the way of the world.

Comment: @brian_p -- I was out of the office yesterday for an all-day meeting, so I could not reply to your question.  I edited my question above with the output from the lsusb command you asked for.  That command was issued while the printer was on and had just finished a scan with simple-scanner.  .